# Is there a way to make the active selection more noticeable?

Tags: selection-tools

I'd like to make the active selection color different because I can barely see it when I'm selecting faces. I have an object that I'm trying to UV map, and there are some tiny faces that haven't unwrapped the way I expected, which I can see in the UV map editor, but can't find in 3D view because the active selection is too hard to see.

Comment: Did you try it with wireframe shading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- Switch you view to user preferences. Select 3D View from the left.  You will find what you need
- Consider Zooming.  Number Pad (.) period then you can zoom at center.
- User preferences allows you increase the size of the outline and vertex dots